# Not able to create API keys for JSS App in core database - Sitecore 9.1 and JSS

Tags: jss

I am playing around with JSS App with **Sitecore 9.1.0 (rev. 001564)**. I have followed the youtube video for [Build Your First JSS App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNQGsr9_34A) and I have been stuck at one point where I need to create the API Keys to integrate JSS App with my Sitecore instance as shown below:

[image]

But I could not find the Services folder under which API Keys should be created:

[image]

I checked the steps multiple times and did not miss any step until the API Keys are created.

Do I need to install any other package or module for this or I have missed something while installing Sitecore instance?

**Note**

This is a fresh Sitecore 9.1 instance and I did not get any issue/error while installing.

Any help/pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the folder for services is now on the master database. Please check on master database and at the same path (`/sitecore/system/Settings/Services`)

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Yes you are correct. Services folder is in master database. I think the content in video is from older version, I found this video on top articles that create some confusion her. Thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Sitecore 9.1, you should use the `master` database instead of the `core`. This has been changed in Sitecore 9.1 as specified in the [Release Notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/91/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2091%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes). There is no more the need of the `core` database on a CD Server as Sitecore security membership provider is not used.

So, due to this, they moved the `Services` folder to the master database. On master database, navigate to the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys` and it is there that you'll be able to create the API Key.

You can also have more information on creating an API Key at [Sitecore 9.1 documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/api-keys-for-the-odata-item-service.html)